# How to post JSON to Spring server?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, backend

I get a list of object from server. One key of this objects is called `body`, and it is a `json`. It is almost impossible for me to know its keys  : the `key name` and  size of it (`body`) are different.

### Example of data

`data from server = [object, object, object,.....]`

```js
object = {
  id: 1,
  name: "xyz",
  body": {
    x: "xyz",
    y: "xyz",
    z: "xys",
  }
}
```

I edit the `body` and then post it to the `server` together with the `id` of the object. Until here it is fine. I can send the request but can not handle the `Requestparam` which is of type `json`.

How  to handle this post request on the backend built in `Java` and `Spring`?

Comment: Are you asking how to make a post request or how to handle a post request on the backend? Either way you should provide more details other than just `spring`.

Comment: Tip: All arbitrary (valid) JSON can be represented as a `Map<String, Object>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a `@RequestBody` annotation to the method on the Controller such as:

```
@RequestMapping ("url/to/save")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseObject send (@RequestBody RequestObject myRequestObject)
{
   //do something

   return new ResponseObject ();
}
```

The `RequestObject` would be the Java Class mapping to the JSON you want to save. The `ResponseObject` is whatever you want to return, you could also return `void` but Firefox has issues with that sometimes.

Comment: Thanks. But the `JSON`  has arbitrary `keys` and `size`. Could you tell me how to map it to a Java Class?

Comment: If it's arbitrary, you could possibly put a `Map` instead of a Java Class.

Comment: Thanks. For the answer and the comment.